# Ranking diagonal values of matrix in ascending order and other than diagonal values depending on diagonal values in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, bsxfun

Input matrix:

```
    1.0000         0    0.2173    0.2585    0.3764
         0         0         0         0         0
    0.2173         0    0.2173    0.2173    0.2173
    0.2585         0    0.2173    0.2585    0.2585
    0.3764         0    0.2173    0.2585    0.3764
```

Expected output matrix:

```
       5    1    2    3    4
       1    1    1    1    1
       2    1    2    2    2
       3    1    2    3    3
       4    1    2    3    4
```

For given matrix R={r(i,j)} following are the 2 operations done for input matrix:

1.We rank diagonal values in ascending order.(i.e for small value rank 1 is given and for next small value rank2 and so on)

```
 ex:
     0-1st rank
0.2173-2nd rank
0.2585-3rd rank
0.3764-4th rank
1.0000-5th rank
```

2.Other than diagonal cell  we sort rest values rowise depending on diagonal value.(i.e diagonal value rank is given to other matrix values)

```
    ex:For 1st row           For 2nd row       For 3rd row      For 4th row     For 5th row


      0-1st rank             0-1st rank         0-1st rank          0-1st rank        0-1st rank 
 0.2173-2nd rank             0-1st rank    0.2173-2nd rank     0.2173-2nd rank   0.2173-2nd rank
 0.2585-3rd rank             0-1st rank    0.2173-2nd rank     0.2585-3rd rank   0.2585-3rd rank
 0.3764-4th rank             0-1st rank    0.2173-2nd rank     0.2585-3rd rank   0.3764-4th rank
```

Source code i tried:

```
 out = zeros(size(table1));


for k = 1:5
    [~,ind2] = sort(table1(k,:));

    ind2(ind2)=1:5;
    out(k,:) = ind2;

end


out = out-bsxfun(@gt,out,diag(out));

%%// Take care of assigning diagonal elements
[~,ind1] = sort(diag(table1));
ind1(ind1)=1:5;
out(1:size(out,1)+1:end)=ind1;

C=out
```

Output matrix i got:

```
 5     1     2     3     4
 1     1     2     3     4
 2     1     2     3     4
 3     1     2     3     4
 4     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all values are present in the diagonal... all you need to do is replace all values with positive integers whilst maintaining the ordering of the numbers...

The third output of unique will give a column vector of all the values in A but replacing the lowest value with 1, second lowest with 2 and so on... which can then be reshaped into a matrix of size A

### Code

```
[~,~,temp]=unique(A);
out=reshape(temp,size(A))
```

### Result

```
out =

     5     1     2     3     4
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     1     2     2     2
     3     1     2     3     3
     4     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that sort doesn't merge duplicate values. You probably need to add something in your for loop to ensure that identical values have identical indexes. Perhaps something like the following:

```
for k = 1:5
  [val,ind2] = sort(table1(k,:));
  [uval, uvi] = unique(val); 
  ind2b = ind2; 
  for ki = 1:length(uval)
    ind2b(val == uval(ki)) = ki;
  end
  out(k,:) = ind2b;
end
```

The code snippet I have posted above finds the set of unique values in each row, and then assigns a single index per value group.